# Unable to pass parameters in powershell while deploying ARM Template from Blob Storage

Tags: json, azure, powershell, templates, azure-resource-manager

I am new here. Hope someone could help me with this.

I am deploying a basic networkInterface(as a test) through Azure arm template using the New-AzResourceGroupDeployment cmdlet. I am using a json template file and a json parameters file:

createNic.json
&
createNic.parameters.json

While referencing both json files locally from my pc I am able to pass NicName parameter successfully and create networkInterfaces with the NicName.

Like so:

```js
New-AzResourceGroupDeployment `
-Name 'CreateNic' `
-ResourceGroupName 'TestRG' `
-TemplateFile 'C:\json\createNic.json' `
-TemplateParameterFile 'C:\json\createNic.parameters.json' `
-NicName 'Test-Nic'
```

I want to deploy the networkInterfaces by storing and referencing both json files from my azure blob storage using the Storage Blob SAS Tokens.

My powershell deployment code works as long as I dont include the

-NicName 'My-Test-Nic'

parameter in my New-AzResourceGroupDeployment cmdlet. When I do, I get following error message:

**New-AzResourceGroupDeployment : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'NicName'**

I have also verified that my SAS tokens and URLs are accessible by pasting them into browser.

If I do not include '-NicName' parameter. The networkInterface successfully creates in my test resource groups using the default values from templates json file.

**My powershell deployment code:**

```js
$secret = (Get-AzKeyVaultSecret -VaultName 'xxxx-xxx-key-vault' -Name 'xxstorageaccount').SecretValueText
$StorageContext = New-AzStorageContext -StorageAccountName 'xxstorageaccount' -StorageAccountKey $secret

$templateuri = New-AzStorageBlobSASToken `
  -Container 'json-container-templates' `
  -Context $StorageContext `
  -Blob 'createNic.json' `
  -Permission rw `
  -ExpiryTime (Get-Date).AddHours(2.0) -FullUri

Write-Host 'templateuri'
$templateuri

$TemplateParameterUri = New-AzStorageBlobSASToken `
  -Container 'json-container-templates' `
  -Context $StorageContext `
  -Blob 'createNic.parameters.json' `
  -Permission rw `
  -ExpiryTime (Get-Date).AddHours(2.0) -FullUri

Write-Host 'TemplateParameterUri'
$TemplateParameterUri


    New-AzResourceGroupDeployment `
    -Name 'CreateNic' `
    -ResourceGroupName 'TestRG' `
    -TemplateUri $templateuri `
    -TemplateParameterUri $TemplateParameterUri `
    -NicName 'My-Test-Nic'
```

My createNic Json code:

```js
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "NicName": {
            "type": "String"
        },
        "virtualNetworks_xx_xxx_VNET_externalid": {
            "type": "String"
        }
    },
    "variables": {},
    "resources": [
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces",
            "apiVersion": "2020-05-01",
            "name": "[parameters('NicName')]",
            "location": "northcentralus",
            "tags": {
                "displayName": "VM-Nic"
            },
            "properties": {
                "ipConfigurations": [
                    {
                        "name": "ipconfig1",
                        "properties": {
                            "privateIPAddress": "10.150.16.36",
                            "privateIPAllocationMethod": "Dynamic",
                            "subnet": {
                                "id": "[concat(parameters('virtualNetworks_xx_xxx_VNET_externalid'), '/subnets/xxx-xx-Pool')]"
                            },
                            "primary": true,
                            "privateIPAddressVersion": "IPv4"
                        }
                    }
                ],
                "dnsSettings": {
                    "dnsServers": []
                },
                "enableAcceleratedNetworking": false,
                "enableIPForwarding": false
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

My createNic Parameters Json code:

```js
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentParameters.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "NicName": {
            "value": "My-Test-Nic"
        },
        "virtualNetworks_xx_xxx_VNET_externalid": {
            "value": "/subscriptions/xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx-xx/resourceGroups/xx-xxx-Networking/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/xx-xxx-VNET"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you take a look [here](https://mcpmag.com/articles/2019/07/16/powershell-for-parametrized-arm-templates.aspx) you can see the snippet of PowerShell where the Author passes in custom parameters.

```
$paramObject = @{
    'webAppName' = 'AdbPluralsightWebApp'
    'sqlDbName'  = 'webappdb'
}
$parameters = @{
    'Name'                  = 'ContosoWebAppDeployment'
    'ResourceGroupName'     = 'ContosoWebApp'
    'TemplateFile'          = 'C:\\armtemplate.json'
    'TemplateParameterObject'    = $paramObject
    'Verbose'               = $true
}

New-AzResourceGroupDeployment @parameters
```